# How to remove scribbles on a screenshot

Tags: adobe-photoshop, jpg, image-editing

Is there any possible way to restore the original screenshot (JPEG) after been scribbled?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: It's not possible. There's no recoverable image data.

Comment: This is like asking.. "can I remove the basil from my marinara sauce after it's made?"

Comment: @Scott except, although extremely painstakingly time consuming...  *removing the basil*, would actually be possible. (Unlike this)

Answer (score 11):

No.

A JPG is a raster image with no concept of layers or history or anything of the kind that would let you revert it to a previous state or remove anything leaving what was underneath intact.

The only solution is to find the original file (version history in Dropbox or Google Drive comes to mind) or some other non-graphic-related technical solution.